# Can secure erase be interrupted?

Tags: disk-utility, secure-erase

Does it trash the disk if I interrupt the secure erase option of Disk Utility?

There's nothing on the disk to hide, so I don't want to waste time, but if I triggered it accidentally — blame the cat :-) — will that render the disk unusable?

Comment: How does one “accidentally”  securely erase a disk?

Comment: @Allan trying to add a partition or reformatting the disk and accidentally clicking the secure erase checkbox.

Answer (score 2):

You can interrupt a secure erase mid-process.  Will it render the disk unusable?

Yes and no.

Yes in that anything written will likely be severely corrupted. Any pre-existing data is toast. No in that your drive will not be physically damaged. You can re-partition and reformat to work with Apple computers, Linux/Unix, and PCs.

Comment: Pre-existing data will be toast in an erase whether secure or not, interrupted or not.

Comment: You have a much better chance of recovering data from a an insecure erase as only the pointers are deleted. My answer addresses the broad  question you asked.  If I didn’t address it in this manner, my inbox would be flooded from other readers with comment “the data is destroyed making it unusable.”

Comment: This is quite a helpful answer, the only thing I'm left wondering is, if interrupting the 7 pass erasure requires the disk to be re-partitioned and reformatted to work, how difficult is that? E.g. I'm a total newbie (I've never partitioned a disk before and have hardly used Disk Utility, will I be able to do it, or is it a job for the experts?)

Comment: Partitioning a drive is easy @stevec.  Start by taking a blank flash drive and trying the different options to get a feel for it.  You can do this a zillion times and not damage things.  Once comfortable, do it it on your “production”.  You’ll be safe that way